# Cannabis Data Set

Tags: data-request, biology

Looking for a data set of cannabis information. Already found the genome info off of amazon, but would be interested to know if there are any other botanical datasets out there like season cycles, nutrient sensitivity, etc. They do not need to be genome datasets, just need to be cannabis/hemp related :)

The idea being to be able to apply predictive models to the data with hopes of understanding in what conditions optimize growth and ultimately yield.

Comment: Can you refine the type of information you are looking for like cannabis usage or botanique related data ...

Comment: Usage would be interesting too, but what i was really hoping for was botanical information, like season cycles, nutrient sensitivity, etc. The idea being to be able to apply predictive models to the data with hopes of understanding in what conditions optimize growth and ultimately yield. - FYI I live in a state where it is legal to grow hemp ;)

Comment: Im also looking for Cannabis ' grow data', can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6):

Try the sites linked at the bottom of http://www.theplantlist.org/tpl1.1/record/kew-2696480, particularly NCBI one.

Just about the seeds: http://data.kew.org/sid/SidServlet?ID=4439&Num=5E7

Answer (score 4):

try the seedbank:
http://en.seedfinder.eu/database/
for example here's some climate info:
http://en.seedfinder.eu/research/climate/zones/BlHm2/

Answer (score 2):

You can also check commercial seedbanks for the latest strains:
http://www.midweeksong.com/
truenorthseedbank.com
sensiseeds.com/en

United States Cannabis Seed Banks - http://www.calgarycmmc.com/unitedstatescannabis.htm

Comment: pretty sure "latest strains" doesn't fall under botanical dataset, midweek song is entirely sales, us cannabis seed banks may have data, but it reads like sales....so cough up some relevant information or i'm going to have drop a dime on you and flag this for closing.

Answer (score 2):

I would try out http://www.weedseedreview.net or http://www.dank.guru if you are looking for specific strain information.

Comment: can you provide more information regarding the two sites? specifically what information they offer as open data?